# Failing to connect to SQL Server from C#

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to import excel file into SQL Server 2005 in C#, but I', getting an error.

Here's my code:

```
namespace excel
{
public partial class Csharp_Excel : Form
{
    public Csharp_Excel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        path = Path.Combine(path, "csharp-Excel.xls");

        string connStr = @"Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Data Source= C:\\Users\\adil pc\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\excel\\excel\\bin\\Debug\\csharp-Excel.xls;Initial Catalog=RMS;Integrated Security=SSPI;";

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        string strCmd = "select * from [sheet1$A1:E7]";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strCmd, con);

        try
        {
           con.Open();
            ds.Clear();
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            da.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {             
        }
    }

    private void btnsend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

The error that I am getting is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specified error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Comment: If you get SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio), you could import the excel directly.

Comment: no I want to do it through c# as user will upload it

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working I made some changes in connection string :

```
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\csharp-Excel.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";
```

it is working on demo havent implement in actual project once I do will update.